# To be able to derive selected code or design from requirements - what does it mean?

Tags: testing, verification, requirements

ISO 12207 contains interesting points for design verification:

> a) The design is correct and consistent with and traceable to
>   requirements.
>
> c) Selected design can be derived from requirements.

Also under Core verification, it reads:

> c) Selected code can be derived from design or requirements.

What does it mean? What is the difference between those?

Answer (score 0):

Here the 3 important phases of software life-cycle mentioned i.e.:

1. Requirements
2. Design
3. Code

It means your code must be accurately derived from design and your design must be according to your requirements